# How to differentiate between selected pictures in VBA code excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am a total beginner in VBA coding. 
I try to arrange 3 pictures in Excel as follows:

1. Bring all selected pictures to the same size.
2. Bring the 3 selected pictures 188 point away from each other in 1 row.

My problem is that I have no idea how to differentiate beween the pictures. With my code the pictures overlap. Thats my code:

```
Sub ArrangePics()

' ArrangePics Macro

    Dim objPic As Object

    For Each objPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        With objPic.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(4.1)
            .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(5.1)
        End With
    Next

    Selection.ShapeRange.Distribute msoDistributeHorizontally, msoFalse


Dim intX As Integer
intX = 1
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To 2 Step 1

   Selection.ShapeRange.Left = intX * 188

Next


'       Selection.Cut

End Sub
```

I would be very grateful for help.Thanks.

Michael Sluck

Comment: I believe your picture objects are an array: `objPic[0]`, `objPic[1]`, `objpic[2]`, and so on. As far as which picture `objPic[0]` is I don't know how excel decides to numbers them. Maybe there is a `.name` attribute or something. Good luck.

Comment: I got a great answer at [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083722/how-to-differentiate-between-selected-pictures-in-vba-code-excel)

Answer (score 0):

I belive this will solve the problem.

```
Sub ArrangePics()
' ArrangePics Macro
    Dim dNextPos As Double, _
        objPic As Object


    For Each objPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures

        With objPic.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(4.1)
            .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(5.1)
            .Left = dNextPos

            dNextPos = .Left + .Width + 188
        End With

    Next

'    Selection.ShapeRange.Distribute msoDistributeHorizontally, msoFalse
End Sub
```